# Can't get webpack to work client-side with Babel

Tags: webpack, vue.js, babeljs

[Full Code here](https://github.com/write-io/write.io/tree/single-file-components)

I'm trying to implement [Vue Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) using express/handlebars. According to that page, I went & installed Webpack (and then Babel).

Superficially, Webpack is working:

```
webpack built 770ca5c82f424a41909d in 285ms
Hash: 770ca5c82f424a41909d
Version: webpack 1.14.0
Time: 285ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  1.84 kB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} bundle.js (main) 428 bytes [rendered]
    [0] ./public/client.js 428 bytes {0} [built]
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

This is my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>writing.io</title>
    
    <script src="public/bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import Home from './Home.vue';
    import Game from './Game.vue';

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        render: h => h(Home)
    })
    ...
```

I'm getting `unexpected token import` on `import Vue from 'vue';` (which "should" work with Babel now).

Tried replacing that line with `var Vue = require('Vue').Vue`, but then `require` isn't recognized.

What am I missing?

Comment: I can't see Vue loader defined in your webpack file - as I know it's required for Single File Components

Comment: @BelminBedak - I'm trying to get it to work... what I found is a complete generator using `vue-cli`. Looking to adapt my current project, not start it from scratch... still not sure how to do with that loader.

Comment: Take look at my example repo webpack.config.js file, and you will see how to init vue-loader (make sure you have installed it via npm), also take look at the .babelrc file - https://github.com/bedakb/vuewp

Comment: And btw I can't even see vue into your packages.json

Comment: @BelminBedak thanks, works like a charm (well, encountering other errors now, but _this_ one seems to be solved).

Comment: If you convert your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working :) Answer added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first I can't see the vue-loader defined into your webpack file, so consider about adding it as loader because It's required when you want to work with Single File Components.

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './public/client.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/public'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" },
      { test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue' }
    ]
  }
};
```

Also make sure, you have vue-loader installed in your app via npm/yarn.

And at the end make sure you have VueJS installed

Comment: Hmm, actually I fixed a bunch of dependency errors, my bundle.js is now bigger (as it should be), but I'm back to the original error - in my .vue files, neither `import` nor `require` is defined.

Comment: Hm, let me resarch it a bit, need some time to look possible issues.

Comment: Okay, I think I found it - so you have client.js as entry file, but there I can't see any vue related thing imported, so webpack doesn't see vue here - consider about moving things from index.html (js part) to client.js - see how I did it here https://github.com/bedakb/vuewp/blob/master/public/app/themes/vuewp/app/app.js - for me this is entry file in webpack

Comment: Yeah I found the same thing concurrently. Thanks a million!